# Rsa Cryptography in c#. i have encrypted an xml file and saved it

Tags: c#

Rsa Cryptography in c#. i have encrypted an xml file and saved it .after that i transferred this file to another pc .the main problem is that it couldn,t decrypt.i dont know why??
when iam decrypting on the same machine the xml file is decrypted..

```
 public static byte[] decryptFile(XmlDocument Doc, RSA rsaKey, string KeyName)
        {
```

Doc = new XmlDocument();

        Doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        Doc.Load(@"MLPACK1.xml");
        EncryptedXml encXml = new EncryptedXml(Doc);
        encXml.AddKeyNameMapping(KeyName, rsaKey);

        encXml.DecryptDocument();
        string contentOfDocument = Doc.OuterXml;
        byte[] buffer = StrToByteArray(contentOfDocument);

        return buffer;

    }

Comment: And why it is community wiki ???

Answer (score 2):

You have used [ProtectedData.Protect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.protect.aspx)(....) method.
Third parameter of the method is scope(enum) type of [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dataprotectionscope.aspx).

So seems you have set DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine (or even may be DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser) for DPS and passed it to Protect method.

Like this

```
DataProtectionScope DPS = DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine
ProtectedData.Protect(bytes, null, DPS);
```

So this can be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is your key the same on both machines? You should take the public key from the machine where this will be **decrypted** and use this to encrypt it on the other machine.